# Android App crashes due to adding a layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, forceclose

I have the following initialization in my java file:

```
Button btnCalc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
final Button btnClearWin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
final Button btnSaveTrip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
final EditText nameOfInf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
final EditText tollAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etToll);
final EditText showLog = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etShowLog);
showLog.setFocusable(false);

final View lineView = (View) findViewById(R.id.vwLine);
final TextView tvTotalLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
final TextView tvTotalAmountLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotalAmount);

final TextView tvNameLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
final TextView tvTollLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvToll);

final RadioGroup rgTypeOfInf = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgType);
final RadioGroup rgTypeOfTrip = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgTripType);
```

Originally everything was working fine until I moved some of the objects to a different layout which is no longer in `main` layout file and now my application FC when it's opening.

The following are in a different layout, `result.xml`. Do I have to initialize them separately?

```
final EditText showLog = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etShowLog);
showLog.setFocusable(false);
final Button btnClearWin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
final Button btnSaveTrip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
```

When I comment out the above four lines, the application opens just fine.

Logcat:

```
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.testing/com.test.testing.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at com.test.testing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
07-25 10:27:27.955: E/AndroidRuntime(13791):    ... 11 more
07-25 10:27:27.963: W/ActivityManager(381):   Force finishing activity com.test.testing/.MainActivity
07-25 10:27:28.517: W/ActivityManager(381): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4163fe28 u0 com.test.testing/.MainActivity}
07-25 10:27:28.666: I/qtaguid(381): Failed write_ctrl(s 0 10116) res=-1 errno=1
07-25 10:27:28.666: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(381): setKernelCountSet(10116, 0) failed with errno -1
07-25 10:27:38.666: W/ActivityManager(381): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{4163fe28 u0 com.test.testing/.MainActivity}
07-25 10:28:00.166: D/dalvikvm(2069): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3198K, 52% free 13534K/27904K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 29ms
07-25 10:28:00.166: D/dalvikvm(2069): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 23ms
```

Comment: What do you mean with "other than main"?

Comment: please post you logcat output as well

Comment: You can initialize views that are in your layout xml that is set to the activity. if its in a different xml and you try to initialize you get NPE.

Comment: So how do I initialize a button from `result` layout in my java file?

Comment: you need to inflate that layout result.xml  and then use that inflated view object to initialize your views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use views from other layout other than the main layout then you need to inflate that layout. If you do not inflate and use its views directly it will give NPE

Example Code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout mFrame = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.results, null);   
//Now you can use/reference its resources/views etc.
final EditText showLog = (EditText)mFrame.findViewById(R.id.etShowLog);
showLog.setFocusable(false);
final Button btnClearWin = (Button) mFrame.findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
final Button btnSaveTrip = (Button) mFrame.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
```

Comment: I would add that under the onCreate() method?

Comment: Yes you can, make sure its before using views defined in that layout. I have updated the code. Also make sure you use the appropriate Layout for mFrame. If its LinearLayout change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout

Comment: What if it uses multiple layouts? Both Relative and Linear, not that I am using two.

Comment: Each android layout file can have only one root/main layout. Root/Main layout can have multiple layouts inside it. So you inflate the layout .xml file using the main/root layout.

Comment: Aaaaahhhh... I understand. Thanks! If you don't mind can you please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861585/slide-in-another-xml-layout-when-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 1):

What i saw from your code "maybe" only this code produces error:

`showLog.setFocusable(false)`

Try to check for null first before setting any value

`if (showLog != null)
  showLog.setFocusable(false);`

Comment: To complete the assignment, you need to set showLog.setFocusable(false) on the activity where you inflate the appropriate layout. Therefore you will get it right.

Comment: I do have another issue. The issue is, I am trying to display some value in a different layout file when clicked on current layout file. Do you have an email I can send u my Java Code?

Comment: I believe if you have more issue, it would be more appropriate and fair if you post it in SO as anybody can give suggestions or answers, right? :)

Comment: Mind taking a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861585/slide-in-another-xml-layout-when-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 0):

After you move or rename files or resources, you have to cleanup and build the project for the new references.

Comment: this has nothing to with NPE.

Comment: Sure, if the object couldn't be initialized, you'll get an NPE

Answer (score 0):

For an activty when you use setcontentview(layout). Only that xml layout view you can reference to your activity. For other xml,you have to inflate that XML as a view.