# Slide in another XML layout when button is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a `main.xml` layout file and in my Java code, I am doing some calculation taken from the `main` layout and wanting to display in `result.xml` layout file. I know I can use the `anim` folder to hold the animation to slidei n the `result` layout like the following:

left to right:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

right to left:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
     android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

I was wondering how to implement the above so when the button is clicked on the `main` layout file, the `result` layout file slides in from the right. And also if I wanted to go back to the `main` layout I can press a button (added on `result` layout) to slide right the `main` layout file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use this function : [overridePendingTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) which can define an animation for the upcoming activity and an other animation for the activity which exit.

Use it like this, in your second Activity :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_out_right, 0);
    setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
```

first argument is for the animation enter, and 0 is for no animation.

And for an animation when you leave your second activity :

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enterAnim, R.anim.leaveAnim);
}
```

Comment: I think that's exactly what I need but the only issue I am having is adding it to my code

Comment: @SiKni8 put this method like i write, in `onCreate()` and `finish()` of your second Activity

Comment: So I should have two xml files and two activities?

Comment: Yes, it's one of the possibilities.

Comment: Can I send you what I have?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34382/discussion-between-meph-and-sikni8)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use default stock animations supplied by Android framework.

Heres an example code:

```
boolean isFirstXml=evaluatingConditionFunction();
LayoutInflater inflator=getLayoutInflater();
View view=inflator.inflate(isFirstXml?R.layout.myfirstxml:R.layout.myseconxml, null, false);
view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right));
setContentView(view);
```

Call this from any of your activity which holds your Parent View.

For custom animations you can visit developer docs. Heres the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) link.

Comment: I am actually trying to call the second xml after the button is clicked, so should I initialize on under onCreate and call the second xml inside the button click? I added the entire code inside the onClick method of my button, `evaluatingConditionFunction()` and `LoadAnimation()` is throwing an error.